# Trying to create a line with a function and then print it with another function

Tags: c, function, line

guys. I'm a beginner and have to create a function that returns a line of output type Line from inputs y intercept and slope, and create another function that prints it. When I run the functions, it mostly prints right, but x prints as 0.00. I need it to print as an x variable because I will later be  making a function that finds the intercept of two lines.

Here's the create function:

```
Line createLine (double m, double b) {
    Line y;
    double x;
    y.m = m;
    y.b = b;
    //y = y.m * x + y.b;  get an error saying the types dont match so I stopped using this  
    return y;
```

The print function:

```
void displayLine (Line a){
     double x;
    printf("y = %lf * %lf + %lf\n", a.m, x, a.b);
```

And the struct:

```
typedef struct line_struct{
    double m;
    double b;
} Line;
```

I also have a point struct if it matters.

Comment: `x` is never initialized. You need to assign something to it.

Comment: and the `printf` message suggests there is a multiplication, which is not there.

Comment: @Schwern I just wanted to create/print something like y = 4x +3, instead of y = 4(value of x) + 3

Comment: @BepisKid how would you get the value of 'x'? Or you just want to **print** x?

Comment: Please extract and provide a [mcve]. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming the variable `x` will get *printed* as the output, but the way you've desired won't work. The `x` is an identifier name and hence, it can't be used to print its name itself.

Thus, you don't need to use any other stuff here at all. Just simply print `x` in the `printf()` statement and you're done.

Also, note that, as per of your requirement, we've used `int` datatype here rather than using `double`, the double is only required when you need to show a very large floating point value which can't be held by the `float` itself.

---

You may try this way to achieve:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct line_struct {
    int m;
    int b;
} Line;

Line createLine(int m, int b) {
    Line y;
    y.m = m;
    y.b = b;

    return y; // returning the initialized struct to the function correctly
}

void displayLine (Line a){
    printf("y = %dx + %d\n", a.m, a.b); // displaying a simple 'x'
}

int main(void) {
    Line l;
    l.b = 3;
    l.m = 4;

    displayLine(l);

    return 0;
}
```

This will give you the desired output:

```
y = 4x + 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to print the line `y = 4x + 3`, you don't need a variable called `x` at all.  This will suffice:

```
printf("y = %lf x + %lf\n", a.m, a.b);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the createLine function.
I hope it works this way.

```
Line createLine (double m, double b) {
    Line y;
    double x;
    y.m = m*x;
    y.b = b;
    return y;
}
```

Comment: The OP wants the `x` letter to be printed, rather than printing the value of `x`.